# I have a question about wasserstein distance

Tags: optimal-transport

Given the wasserstein distance of order two,
$$d(\mu_{1},\mu_{2})^{2}=inf_{p\in P(\mu_{1},\mu_{2})}\int_{R^{n}\times R^{n}}|x-y|^{2}p(dxdy)$$
Is there $d(\mu_{1},\mu_{2})=d(\mu_{2},\mu_{1})$ or $d(\mu_{1},\mu_{2})=-d(\mu_{2},\mu_{1})$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The title speaks nothing about the problem. MathJax works even in titles, so don't hesitate to use it there

Answer (score 1):

One can show that the Wasserstein is a distance/metric on the space of probability measures, therefore we have symmetry, i.e. $d(\mu_1, \mu_2) = d(\mu_2, \mu_1)$. See for instance this [reference](https://lchizat.github.io/files2020ot/lecture3.pdf).